# Borders for CDE Table Component

Tags: pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

I want to add borderline for my table component (not between the cells but only around the table) but unable to do so, as for now I have added this thing in pre-exe but something different happened I think I am missing something with the below code?

PRE_EXEC:

```
table td {
    border-left: 1px solid #A9A7A1;
    border-right: 1px solid #A9A7A1;
    border-top:1px solid #A9A7A1;
    border-bottom:1px solid #A9A7A1;
    height: 20px;
    font-size:14px;
    /*padding-left: 10px;*/
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

so what I want to do in order to get it work?

Comment: This code you pasted here is CSS, not Javascript. Therefore you cannot use it on the `preExecution` hook.

Comment: @ÓscarGómezAlcañiz Yes you are right! I was beginner then, now i came to this :)